# How to write a program which will be running automatically, whenever I turn on my computer, in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am creating a process every time but after "kill -9 -1", I lost the process that I created. I know why I lost it every time..
But is there anyway, so that I can make my program run automatically, every time I turn on my computer??

thanks,,

Comment: There's not enough information to give a good answer.  The GRUB or GRUB2 bootloader that probably loads Linux for your computer can do many things, but it seems likely that you want a program that runs with permissions of a user (you), which suggests an approach based on when you login.  It may be that this is the wrong forum for your question.

Comment: Isn't this question better asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1):

Most distributions still support [SysV Init Scripts](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html).

The easiest way to do it is to take a simple init script from `/etc/init.d/` and change it to suit your needs:

```
sudo cp /etc/init.d/foo /etc/init.d/my_foo
sudo gedit /etc/init.d/my_foo
```

Then, you'll need to enable it:

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig my_foo on
```

If `chkconfig` isn't available, you may need to install it.  Also, there are LSB aliases like `insserv` which might be available.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu systems now come with [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), whose configuration files may be a bit less verbose than with System V `init` scripts. A simple job configuration for Upstart would look like this, and go into, say, `/etc/init/example.conf`:

```
# this is a comment
start on startup
stop on shutdown
exec /path/to/program --some-args maybe-another-arg
```

Then it'll start and stop, well, on startup and on shutdown, respectively. To manually start and stop it, use the `start` and `stop` commands as `root`:

```
$ sudo start example
$ sudo stop example
```

You can find more information about Upstart configuration in [its Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#configuration). Information is also available in the `init` man page in section 5 on systems where Upstart is installed. (`man 5 init`)

Answer (score 0):

[Supervisor](http://www.supervisord.org/) will let you do that, as well as having some other features like FastCGI support, automatically respawning services if they crash (while being smart about it and not restarting it if it keeps crashing over and over again), and keeping logs of its output.

After it is [installed](http://www.supervisord.org/installing.html) and [itself configured to run on startup](http://www.supervisord.org/running.html#running-supervisord-automatically-on-startup), you can modify its configuration file to add a section that runs a program. A simple example might be like this:

```
; this is a comment
[program:example]
command = /path/to/program --some-args maybe-another-arg
```

That's really all that's necessary for a simple program, but many other configuration options are available; [see the documentation](http://www.supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings).

Once you've added your configuration, you can tell Supervisor to add/remove (and start/stop) any processes you've added or removed from the configuration:

```
$ sudo supervisorctl update
```

You can manually start and stop services if you want to, as well:

```
$ sudo supervisorctl start example
$ sudo supervisorctl stop example
$ sudo supervisorctl restart example
```

You can also see a nifty status display for all of your processes, e.g.:

```
$ sudo supervisorctl status
cgi-pass                         RUNNING    pid 4223, uptime 68 days, 23:57:22
```

And also see what it's recorded of your program's output:

```
$ sudo supervisorctl tail example         # stdout
$ sudo supervisorctl tail example stderr  # stderr
$ sudo supervisorctl tail -f example      # continuous
```

Documentation of the available commands is available with `supervisorctl help`.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora comes with [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd), many other Linux distributions are adopting it (except Ubuntu and for now Debian). The package includes several helper programs you'd might want to look at.